# How to get access token Linkedin?

Tags: ios

1. https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code  &client_id=759l42bhpw7yhf  &scope=r_fullprofile%20r_emailaddress%20r_network. &state=DCEEFWF45453sdffef424 &redirect_uri=http://www.trigma.com
2. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using https://github.com/jeyben/IOSLinkedInAPI . It has examples and a can be integrated through cocoapods.